# How to get rid of highcharts 13 error in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, angular8

Hi i am working on Angular and i want this feature like switching between sections when clicked between the tabs and displaying charts.

I am getting `#13 error` and chart is not being displayed here in second tab how to do it when switching between tabs.

Here is the code so far tried:
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-showdivonclicktoggle-esjoek?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Any solution will be helpful.

Comment: Please copy the code here.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you're removing/readding the rendering container for each If. Move the container outside the conditional rendered diff (*ngIf):

```html
<div> <!-- rendering root -->
  <div>
    <button type="button" (click)="ShowDiv('A');ok()">Show A</button>
    <button type="button" (click)="ShowDiv('B');ok()">Show B</button>
    <button type="button" (click)="ShowDiv('C');ok()">Show C</button>
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <div *ngIf="currDiv == 'A'"></div>
    <div *ngIf="currDiv == 'B'"></div>
    <div *ngIf="currDiv == 'C'"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-showdivonclicktoggle-z2mqb2?file=src/app/app.component.html
UPDATE:
make sure you never remove the div container in your ok function.

```js
#line 96:
Highcharts.chart('container1', {}) // don't do this
Highcharts.chart('container', { /** new chart */ })
```

Also why do you need Ok, you could use ShowDiv?
Also create the click function outside the object (line 173)
Removing the container or replacing it with a new one is like climbing a tree and removing the branch you are sitting on.

Comment: Yeah Looking good, But what happens if i give one more chart https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-showdivonclicktoggle-u9insn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html like this its giving me #13 error.

Answer (score 0):

You might create only one `container` and update the chart after the button click.
It looks much simpler and if you want, you also might add these conditions.

**API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update 

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-showdivonclicktoggle-m54shc**